# Reading external file data at the end of the buffer

Tags: buffers, normal-mode, filesystem

If I am in the middle of the buffer and want to append external file data to the current buffer.
So far I move to end of the file with `G` and reading the data `:r file` so it is doing the work ...... 
Is there any standard style of `vim` reading

Comment: "Is there any standard style of vim reading" What do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for `:$r file`? -- which will move the cursor. Don't forget to play with marks I often use `mx` to mark and `'x` to come back.

You can also use: `:call append('$', readfile('file'))` -- which won't move the cursor. This is what we prefer to use when writing scripts nowadays.

Comment: Note that the `$` is nothing special here; `:read` will accept any range, so something like inserting a text file in line 42 also works: `:42read file`. See [`:help :read`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#%3aread) and [`:help :range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3arange).

Comment: @Luc Hermitte  Thanks for the quick reply and good explanation of answer

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks for extending the answer to +1 level up